# HTML Table Assistance

Tags: html, xhtml, html-table

My table currently isn't doing what I want, and it may just be this hangover but I can't seem to figure out why. Here is what I'm trying to get the table to look like:

[image]

(did that in paint)

Here is my coding:

```
<table border="1">
        <th>Therapeutic Riding</th>
    <tr>
        <td>Joy Adamski</td>
        <td>Driving Instructor in training</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Diana Beardsley</td>
        <td>CHA: Level Three English and Level Two Western (Standard)<br />
        Level Two Physical &amp; Cognitive (IRD)<br />
        PATH International Registered Instructor; Level One Driving Instructor
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tammi Gainer</td>
        <td>CHA: Clinic Instructor in Standard,Vaulting,and IRD<br />
            PATH International Registered Instructor
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Karen Layton</td>
        <td>CHA: Level Two English &amp; Western (Standard)<br />
            Level One Physical &amp; Cognitive (IRD)<br />
            PATH International Registered Instructor
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Audre Mallinak</td>
        <td>PATH International Registered Instructor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Randy Pittis</td>
        <td>CHA: Level Two English &amp; Western (Standard)<br />
            Level One Physical &amp; Cognitive (IRD)<br />
            PATH International Registered Instructor
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Karen Smith</td>
        <td>"Day at the Farm" Group Instructor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tamara Weber</td>
        <td>
            CHA: Level Two English &amp; Western (Standard)<br />
            PATH International Registered Instructor
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `colspan=2` to

`<th colspan=2>Therapeutic Riding</th>`

Also, you should add the following CSS

```
th{
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/gfdTP/

Some `padding` might also help readability

```
th, td{
    padding:.5em;
}
```

Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/gfdTP/1/

Comment: Glad to help @RobertMontz!  Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks @JasonGennaro, a friend recommened me the site,  happy you provided such an extensive answer! In the long-run, this has helped me a bunch :)